# Jquery - Convert drop down menu to radio buttons

Tags: jquery, css, forms, shopify

I have a Shopify product page currently showing my variants as a drop down menu, like below:

[image]

However, I would like to instead show all available options (in in stock) as a set of options like  below. These options should be clickable/selectable:

[image]

Here's the code for the drop down menu, how do I change this to output similar to the screenshot above:

```
  // <![CDATA[  
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
if (variant && variant.available == true) {
// selected a valid variant
jQuery('.button').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled'); // remove unavailable class from add-to-cart button, and re-enable button

{% if product.compare_at_price > product.price %}
    jQuery('.price-field').html(Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "{{shop.money_format}}"));  // update price field

    jQuery('.price-field').addClass('sale').attr('sale', 'sale');

    jQuery('.compare-field').html(Shopify.formatMoney(variant.compare_at_price, "Was     {{shop.money_format}}"));  // update compare field
{% else %}

    jQuery('.price-field').html(Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "{{shop.money_format}}"));  // update price field

{% endif %}

} else {
// variant doesn't exist
jQuery('.button').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');      // set add-to-cart button to unavailable class and disable button
var message = variant ? "Sold Out" : "Unavailable";    
jQuery('.price-field').text(message); // update price-field message
}

};

// initialize multi selector for product
jQuery(function() {
new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select", { product: {{ product | json }}, onVariantSelected: selectCallback });
jQuery('.selector-wrapper').addClass('clearfix');
{% if product.options.size == 1 %}
jQuery('.selector-wrapper').prepend("<label for='product-select-option-0'>{{ product.options.first }}    </label>");
{% endif %}
});
// ]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following this tutorial in the Shopify docs: [Adding color swatches to your products](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/showcasing-products/add-color-swatches-to-your-products)

The tutorial obviously implements colour swatches, but it also implements options that aren't colours as separate buttons instead of a dropdown menu. From the [demo shop](http://yost-hegmann-and-ullrich2101.myshopify.com/):

[image]

Comment: Thats a great find! Didn't even know this existed! Thanks

Comment: @egr103 No problems :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{if ($group.group_type == 'select')}
    <label class="size_attrib">Size</label>
    <select name="{$groupName}" id="group_{$id_attribute_group|intval}" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
    {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
        <option value="{$id_attribute|intval}"{if (isset($smarty.get.$groupName) && $smarty.get.$groupName|intval == $id_attribute) || $group.default == $id_attribute} selected="selected"{/if} title="{$group_attribute|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">{$group_attribute|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</option>
    {/foreach}
    </select>
```

Comment: Answers containing only code are not considered complete. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer